# react-formio: Custom component unmounting

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, formio, react-18

I have a React18 project and wanted to make custom react-formio component (code below) but this.container.unmount in detachReact method shows this warning:

***Warning: Attempted to synchronously unmount a root while React was already rendering. React cannot finish unmounting the root until the current render has completed, which may lead to a race condition.***

is there any way to unmount the element without the warning?

Thanks.

Code:

```
export default class Grid extends ReactComponent {
  ...
  ...

  attachReact(element) {
    this.container = createRoot(element)
    return this.container.render(
      <HistoryRouter history={history}>
        <GridComponent {...{ ...this }} />
      </HistoryRouter>
    )
  }

  detachReact(element) {
    if (element) {
      this.container.unmount() // this creates the race condition warning
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems more of a question with `reactjs` than `formio`, perhaps this question would help: [React 18 async way to unmount root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73459382/react-18-async-way-to-unmount-root). The accepted answer is pretty good.